# R public method in S4 class

Tags: r, oop, class, methods, r-s4

I want to subclass an S4 class and add a special method to that subclass. 
The method should work only for the subclass, it does not make sense for any other class in my application.

```
    setClass("MySpecies", contains="Species", ##Species is an S4 class
         representation(x="numeric"))

setMethod("initialize", "MySpecies", function(.Object, x, ...){
  .Object@x <- x
  args <- list(...)
  for(i in seq_len(length(args))){
    attr(.Object, names(args)[i]) <- args[[i]]
  }
  .Object
})

##CalcMatrix <- function(.Object, y){
##  x <- .Object@x
##  matrix(x, x*2, y*3)
##}

setGeneric("CalcMatrix", function(object, y){standardGeneric("CalcMatrix")})
setMethod("CalcMatrix", "MySpecies",function(object, y){
  x <- object@x
  matrix(x, x*2, y*3)
})
```

With the `setGeneric` it works, but do I really have to define a generic function although it will be used only with this object? The commented out part works, but then there is no check if the function is called with the right arguments. What is the correct way to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In S4, methods belong to functions, not classes.  Once you get that, you'll have a much easier time working with S4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wanting to use method dispatch, and every method needs to be associated with a generic, so yes, `setGeneric` is required.

And for a little unasked-for advice... It's a bit weird to use a formal class system (presumably because the well-defined classes help in writing more complicated programs) and then to subvert the structure by adding arbitrary attributes; these should really be additional, well-defined slots in your class.

Let's make your example reproducible by defining `Species`

```
setClass("Species", representation(y="numeric"))
setClass("MySpecies", contains="Species", ##Species is an S4 class
         representation(x="numeric"))
```

An implicit requirement for S4 classes is that `new("MySpecies")` works; your `initialize` method fails this test (because `x` does not have a default value). In addition, it's common practice to expect that initializing `MySpecies` calls the `initialize` methods for the classes it contains. One could write

```
setMethod("initialize", "MySpecies", function(.Object, ..., x=numeric()) {
    callNextMethod(.Object, x=x, ...)
})
```

Note `callNextMethod`, so that the base class gets initialized properly. Using `...` and passing it to `callNextMethod` means that slots that might be defined in `Species` would also be initialized correctly. Also, `x` needs to be after `...`, because `initialize` is defined to take unnamed arguments that represent contained classes -- `new("MySpecies", new("Species"))` is required to work, even if it is a way of constructing arguments that you do not use directly. The `initialize` method above doesn't actually do anything more than the default initialize method, so in reality (and this is often the case) it makes sense not to write an initialize method at all.

And then in more recent R, `setClass` returns a default constructor so

```
MySpecies <- setClass("MySpecies", contains="Species", ##Species is an S4 class
                      representation(x="numeric"))
```

and then

```
> MySpecies(x=1:5, y=5:1)
An object of class "MySpecies"
Slot "x":
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

Slot "y":
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. In my program, I am extending an existing class to specialize it, so it has two more attributes which I want to access in my method, so it looks like a generic function is the best in that case. Thanks for the `callNextMethod` hint, I did not know that before. The default constructor does not work for me, I get an error: _Error: could not find function "MySpecies"_. I am running R 2.14.1. Is it only available in a newer version?

Comment: Just make the attributes slots in the class definition, rather than tacking them on in an ad hoc way. The constructor was introduced in, I think, the current release R-2.15.

Comment: The default initialize method works fine for all my subclasses, I could get rid of a lot of redundant code!